# How to call a procedure on every time mysql connection created on amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I want to change timezone for amazon RDS for every session. 
RDS timezone by default is UTC.
I want to change it to Asia/Calcutta.

To change timezone for specific session I have defined procedure

```
DELIMITER |  
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.store_time_zone ()  
   IF NOT (POSITION('rdsadmin@' IN CURRENT_USER()) = 1) THEN     
       SET SESSION time_zone = '+5:30';  
   END IF 
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I donot know how should I call it every time new connection/Session is created.

I have taken reference from given link. I am not able to run

```
rds-modify-db-parameter-group PARAMGROUP --parameters "name=init_connect, value='CALL mysql.store_time_zone', method=immediate"
```

It gives error
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rds-modify-db-parameter-group PARAMGROUP --parameters "name=init_connect, value=' at line 1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198369/3551179

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196385/how-to-set-database-timezone-for-a-aws-rds-instance) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141000/adjusting-for-the-default-time-zone-setting-on-rds) as they cover time zones in RDS rather thoroughly.

Comment: Are you trying to run `rds-modify-db-parameter-group` from the command line of MySQL? You must be run `rds-modify-db-parameter-group` from the command line of your operating system. See [Modifying Parameters in a DB Parameter Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.Modifying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you have misunderstood one step, due to ambiguous phrasing in the other answer:

> Connect to your instance, and run the following command

So, you're essentially doing this:

```
mysql> rds-modify-db-parameter-group ...
```

But you should instead be doing this:

```
$ rds-modify-db-parameter-group ...
```

It's not a MySQL statement, it's a shell command.  RDS instances do not have shell access, so you need a different machine to run this command on.  Typically, this might be an EC2 instance, so I assume that's what the other manager's author meant by "your instance," but it could be any machine that has the [RDS command line interface tools installed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/StartCLI.html).

You can also do this from the [RDS Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.Modifying).

---

Note also that you could also do this a bit more concisely, avoiding the stored procedure altogether and even the test for `rdsadmin`, by setting `init_connect` to:

```
SET @@time_zone = '+5:30'
```

The `rdsadmin` user should be immune to `init_connect` because it has the `SUPER` privilege.

> The content of `init_connect` is not executed for users that have the `SUPER` privilege. This is done so that an erroneous value for `init_connect` does not prevent all clients from connecting. For example, the value might contain a statement that has a syntax error, thus causing client connections to fail. Not executing `init_connect` for users that have the `SUPER` privilege enables them to open a connection and fix the `init_connect` value.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect

If you'd rather test for `rdsadmin` anyway...

```
SET @@time_zone = CASE
     WHEN CURRENT_USER() LIKE 'rdsadmin@%' THEN @@time_zone
    ELSE '+5:30' END
```

Setting a variable to the same variable leaves the value unchanged.

Note `@@time_zone` and `SESSION time_zone` are equivalent.