# MySQL time_zone gets reset after restart

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone

It's 15:10 o'clock here but MySQL `SELECT NOW();` says it's 14:10 o'clock.

I fixed it by `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+1:00';`

But after restarting the MySQL server it's the same problem as before.

I also added `default_time_zone = Europe/Berlin` in my `my.cnf` but that results in: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjusting for the default time-zone setting on RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141000/adjusting-for-the-default-time-zone-setting-on-rds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding `default_time_zone = '+1:00'` below `[mysqld]` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

I don't if it'll work after time change on March 26th. I simply created a reminder and I'll check it then.